# Add WCF Service reference using visual studio 2008

Tags: .net, wcf, visual-studio, iis

I want add a service reference, and that end point address  is provided by outside company (the service is hosted in IIS7)  because I need to access to their server to check some data. So they give me a wcf service end point address, I try to add using visual studio 2008, in project select Add service reference.
When I press Go, it give me the error message as below:

The document at the url "xxxxx.com/WCFService/Service.svc" was not recognized as a known document type.
The error message from each known type may help you fix the problem:

- Report from 'DISCO Document' is 'There was an error downloading 'Domainname/ WCFService /Service.svc?disco'.
- The remote name could not be resolved: System name
- Report from "xxxxx.com/ WCFService /" is 'The document format is not recognized (the content type is 'text/html; charset=UTF-8').'.
- Report from 'WSDL Document' is 'The document format is not recognized (the content type is 'text/html; charset=UTF-8').'.
- Report from 'XML Schema' is 'The document format is not recognized (the content type is 'text/html; charset=UTF-8').'.

Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: ://xxxxx.com/WCFService /'.

There was no endpoint listening at https://xxxxx.com/WCFService/ that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.

The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like service URL they gave you isn't valid or the server is down. Try opening the URL in a browser to check this. You might also want to add the WSLD parameter to the service URL when you add the reference: `xxxxx.com/WCFService/Service.svc?wsdl`

Comment: I have already tried by adding the WSDL parameter to the service URL like this : xxxxx.com/WCFService/Service.svc?wsdl

But still it is not working.